# Installing RPM doesn't run all the %install actions listed in .spec

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

TL;DR: I made a .spec file that successfully builds a `.rpm`, but `rpm -i <file>.rpm` doesn't do all the actions I think it should. Why?

Excerpt from `<file>.spec`:

```
%install
sudo python2.7 -m pip install 'tornado<5'
...#other pip commands...
cp -r $RPM_BUILD_DIR/%{name}-%{version}/* %{buildroot}
```

(I know this isn't the ideal way to do it, but I'm forced to use CentOS 6 and can't upgrade the system version of python because corporate/shared environment so this was the best way I could figure out.)

All the commands under `%install` are correctly run when building the `.rpm`, so all of the `pip` packages get installed on the machine creating the `.rpm` from the `.spec`. `rpmbuild -ba <file>.spec` completes with `exit 0`. However, when I try to install the `.noarch.rpm` file that is created (on another system with identical OS/architecture), all that happens is the rpm-specified dependencies get installed and the files get shoved to the correct directories, but the other commands from `%install` are not run. What ends up happening is that I try to call the executable that gets made and it errors out because of the missing python packages.

[RPM.org says:](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-install.html#AEN691)

> Performing any tasks required before the install:
>
> There are cases where one or more commands must be given prior to the actual installation of a package. RPM performs these commands exactly as directed by the package builder, thus eliminating a common source of problems during installations.

...Where am I supposed to specify the commands run prior to package installation if not in the `%install` field of the `.spec` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run commands after the rpm is installed the, you need to place those commands in the `%post` target.

If you want the commands to be run right before the rpm itself is installed, place the commands in the `%pre` target.

The commands in `%install` is executed when you build the .rpm, it is not run when you install the .rpm.

`%install` is intended to install your software onto a sandboxed directory hierarchy which should then be packaged and included into the .rpm file.

Don't run commands in %install that alters any system state or that affects anything outside the $RPM_BUILD_DIR or %{buildroot}

Answer (score 1):

The %install scriptlet is run during build, not while installing.

If you wish commands to be run while installing a package, then you need to use the %post section in the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, `%install` is the script section within a specfile to *copy* the files that have already been compiled during the `%build` phase (which can be a no-op for python). However, others have not yet noted that `sudo python2.7 -m pip install 'tornado<5'` is definitely **not** a command that you should be using in a specfile. You need to get the python files some other way and install them into the proper locations under `%{buildroot}`.

**RPMs should *never* be built as the root user nor call `sudo` *anywhere*. EVER.**

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: I know nothing about the `tornado` package so have nothing to recommend, sorry.