# How to make rpm update install python dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I use rpm to build/install a python project. In the project, all the python dependencies are put in the `requirement.txt`. So my rpm spec file contains something like:

```
%install
...
pip install -r %{build_root}/%{app_dir}/requirement.txt
...
```

My problem is that when rpm update is done, ie:

```
rpm -Uvh python-project-version.rpm
```

pip install is not re-run. This means that newly added python dependencies are not installed on an rpm update. What is the neatest/best solution to this problem?

NOTE: I can always do a uninstall/reinstall of the package to avoid this. I am hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing RPM doesn't run all the %install actions listed in .spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899765/installing-rpm-doesnt-run-all-the-install-actions-listed-in-spec)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brpm-spec%5D+run+python